# How to check multiple list from IPSet in IPTables with a single rule?

Tags: linux, iptables, ipset

How can I check multiple list of IPs from IPSet in IPTables with a single rule?

I need to add check two list of IPs because it is too big. I know it is not healthy, but I need to do it that way.

Current rule:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set trustedlist1 src -j DROP
```

Now I want to make it something like that:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set trustedlist1, trustedlist2 src -j DROP
```

I didnt want to lock myself out.

Comment: Why -1 for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set trustedlist1 src -m set ! --match-set trustedlist2 src -j DROP
```

Better solution is arranging ipset size by providing maxelem option. For example;

```
ipset create trustedlist1 hash:ip maxelem 2000000
```

Comment: Remember that the multiple sets are an effective "and", not "or"; the packet has to match both set expressions: not in list1 and not in list2.